# Show that the set of nonpositive rational numbers is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

Can someone show that the set of nonpositive rational numbers is countable ?

Comment: Sure someone can. What have you tried? [edit] the question to et us know so we can help you.

Comment: Do you know any other sets related to the nonpositive rational numbers that are countable?